# Unable to override methods of LocationListener class

Tags: android, overriding

I want to get current location using GPS.

Here is my scenario. My class definition is:

```
public class UseGps extends Activity implements LocationListener
```

If Í try to override the LocationListener methods like this

1)

```
@Override 
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
```

2)

```
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
```

3)

```
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
```

it is giving me compilation error saying

`The method onStatusChanged(String, int, Bundle) of type UseGps must override a superclass method remove override.`

Same for 2) and 3)

What is wrong here?

Comment: oh sorry.. can you please tell me how to find out the java compliance level which i am using..my jdk version is jdk-6u21-windows-i586

Comment: My guess is that your project is set to compliance level 1.5. You should set it to 1.6.

Comment: yes by default it is 1.5 it seems can you tell me how to set it to 1.6

Comment: hi thanks i have changed it to 1.6 through eclipse..there is no error now you solved my problem thanks Octavian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Eclipse do the following to ensure that your compliance level is 1.6.

Go to `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Java Compiler`. There make sure that `Compiler compliance level` is set to `1.6`.

You should set that level as a default value by navigating to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Compiler`. Select `1.6` for `Compiler compliance level`.

Answer (score 4):

Someone should probably explain that:

1. `@Override` wasn't supported for interfaces until Java 1.6.
2. In Java 1.5, you cannot use `@Override` on a method to indicate it is intended to implement an interface method - the compiler will flag it as an override error.  Under Java 1.5, you can use `@Override` only to indicate that the method is overriding a superclass method.
3. Starting in Java 1.6, you can use `@Override` to indicate the method is intended to implement an interface method (too bad it wasn't a separate annotation like `@Implements`).
4. Eclipse has a feature that can ensure your code compiles under a particular version of Java, regardless of what actual version of Java you have installed - this is the `Compiler Compliance Level`.  If it is set to 1.5, even if your JDK is 1.6, the compiler will flag any code that would not compile under Java 1.5.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained it myself. Thanks for adding the explanation.