# Cannot override onStatusChanged (LocationListener) in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

For some reason, although I implemented `LocationListener` in my Android application, `onStatusChanged` is giving me a "Method does not override method from its superclass" compilation error.

The documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)) specifies that `LocationListener` does contain this method.

Furthermore, I also overrided `onLocationChanged` in my application, but oddly this override does not yield a compilation error.

My code is as follows (with the unrelated parts ellipsed out):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, ErrorDialog.NoticeDialogListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    (...)

    // No error here
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        userLocation = location;
    }

    // Error occurs on this function, however
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
    (...)
}
```

Edit:

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883496/unable-to-override-methods-of-locationlistener-class) SO question, and although our issue seems to be the same, I am running JDK 1.8 (as specified in my project structure, and which is greater than JDK 1.6), so I don't believe that this is a solution, however I am running Android Studio rather than Eclipse. Is there a compiler compliance setting in Android Studio that may be causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883496/unable-to-override-methods-of-locationlistener-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably importing

> com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

and not

> import android.location.LocationListener

Comment: This was it. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!